# How to listen to a smart contract's method being invoked?

Tags: solidity

I'm building a tool that requires listening to functions that are triggered by the developers of smart contracts. I'd like to know if on web3 or ethersjs there is a way to listen to a specific method on the smart contract being invoked. I was going to use the `contract.on` but that seems to only work on contract events, and I need it to listen to contract functions.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: another way is to look at first 4 bytes of tx input data, thats the signature of the function call.

Comment: Make that function trigger an event . Or have a generic event that take name of the function as param

Comment: @AndriyLysak this might actually help me achieve my goal, do you know how I can convert those 4 bytes into a string value to compare to a method name? for example, if the method name is sellTokens, how can I convert the initial 4 bytes of input data to display that string?

Comment: @Adam ok first some theory, hash NEVER converts back to original input, You can make a burger out of a cow, but cant make a cow out of a burger. That being said: you have 2 options, convert the function name to the bytes yourself, its a keccak256 hash OR go to a block explorer like etherscan.io, find a TX that you know has that function call and just copy the first 4 bytes. Also relevant: https://www.4byte.directory/

Comment: @Adam another wrinkle: if you arent 100% sure that other contracts wont delegate to this contract, you will need to keep an eye on INTERNAL transactions as well, same concept, look at first 4 bytes of input data.

Comment: @AndriyLysak Thank you very much, that makes perfect sense, I was wondering if there was a way to fetch the method id and match it against those initial bytes.

Comment: @Adam try this (you need the full function sig):https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html so it would be like sellTokens(address,address,blah,blah) and the first 8 characters is what you want. Test with examples from 4bytes.directory to see how it works

Comment: @AndriyLysak Your last answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!